# How to add dynamic content while creating a dataset in ADF to pull files from a FTP server which has yesterday's date attached to it

Tags: date, dataset, azure-data-factory

I have the following files in the FTP server:
[image: Files]

Each file in the ftp server has the following format: EFS_339751_110_{yesterday_date}

The number before yesterday's date remains the same  always. I need to be able to create a dataset in ADF by picking up the yesterday's file:[image: ADF Pipeline]

I need to be able to add something in the highlighted part of the picture to be able to do that.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on `Add dynamic content` in the file name.

[image]

- Type the below expression in the pipeline expression builder to concat the `EFS_339751_110_` with yesterday's date.

```
@concat('EFS_339751_110_',formatDateTime(getPastTime(1,'Day'),'yyyyMMdd'))
```

**getPastTime()** function returns the current Timestamp (in UTC) minus the specified unit. **formatDateTime()** function returns the value in the specified date format.

- Click Ok.

[image]

- When Preview data is clicked on the dataset, data is shown without any error.
  [image]